# Replicate WindowsCortanaPane as UrlReferrer

Tags: asp.net, bing, cortana

I have a web application (ASP.NET) that received a request for a non-existent web page with a "UrlReferrer" related to https://www.bing.com/AS/API/WindowsCortanaPane/V2/Init

I need to know how to replicate a web request having that information to show my leadership that it is not an error in the application.

I've tried to make some search on Cortana on Windows 10, using Bing from Edge, but I couldn't replicate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The guts of Cortana client on desktop uses edge for rendering.  Did you put up some link from a "search"? When it doubt, get Fiddler logs.

Comment: Hi @Micromuncher, I've tried ussing Fiddler to analyze but when is running the Cortana Search doesn't return information :/
I've tried too pasting the non-existent web page on Cortana search but no result replicating the exception.

Comment: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search > Disable 'Allow Cortana'
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search > Enable 'Don't search the web or display web results in Search'

Comment: Apparently the api call is because of search forwarding a query to web search. This can be controlled via policy. Many enterprises block web results in search...